# Swapping heightmaps to depthmaps

Tags: code-golf

### Description

Your task is to output a 'depthmap' - that is, a heightmap of an object but not seen from its top but from its front.

For example, consider the following object as shown on the image. The height map is shown on the left. The corresponding depth map would be (as seen from standing at the arrow):

```
010
211   <- Depthmap
322
```

If you stand at the arrow, there are 3 cubes behind each other at the bottom left-hand point, 2 behind each other on the middle left-hand point, 0 at the top left-hand point etc.

[image: example]

### Input

Input is a two dimensional array of any sizes (not necessarily square).

### Output

Output is another two dimensional array which represents the depthmap. As you can deduce, its sizes are `(height x width)`. In the image, it would be `(3 x 3)`. Note that if the highest tower of cubes was 5, the depthmap would be an array of `(5 x 3)`.

### Winning condition

The shortest code wins.

### Disallowed

All languages allowed, no explicit restrictions. (I don't know what you can come up with, but play fair please.)

### Examples

```
Input:     Ouput:

5321       0001
1456       1012
2105       1112
           1212
           2222
           3323


Input:     Output:

22         01
13         12
00         22


Input:     Output:    (of the sample image)

232        010
210        211
101        322
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input / output for the example image you posted?

Comment: Can you specify precisely what the depth-map is counting? I can't see a way to interpret the example given with the image consistently.

Comment: I hope the updated image is clearer.

Comment: @pimvdb: Nice puzzle. We encourage people to seek advice on the [Puzzle Lab](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/307/golf-puzzle-lab) char or the [Meta SandBox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/336/78) before posting. That way, these kinds of issues can be ironed out before your puzzle goes live. All of us have trouble producing a perfect specification, especially if the task is non trivial.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm terribly sorry. I honestly think I've included all information now though. Please tell me if there are any problems though.

Comment: Sorry, my stupidity. I was looking from the wrong axis.

Comment: @pimvdb: Don't fret it; it's not some kind of requirement. Just a service we provide for each other in hope of making the site a little better.

Comment: What's the correct output for an input of `[[0 0] [0 0]]`? The empty array `[]`?

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Yes, its height is 0 so its dimensions are 0 x 2, which basically comes down to an empty array.

Comment: It would not be 323 the correct value for the 3rd line?

Comment: @Joey: Yes indeed, I'm sorry. I'm really going to discuss in the chat before posting next time... @Adilson de Almeida Jr: No, have a look at the picture. There are only two behind each other on the bottom right hand point if you stand at the arrow.

Comment: Well, the confusion regarding the last line might be that your definition of »depth map« is uncommon, I guess. Usually a depth map is the same as a height map, just seen from a specific camera – i.e. it tells the extension towards the viewpoint of a given scene (at least that's how 3D renderers treat it). What you have is essentially a how many blocks are behind each other in a given place. Not sure how to call it, though. An anlogy might be partially transparend glass blocks and the more you have of them behind each other, the darker the result gets – regardless of space between them.

Comment: @Joey: I wasn't aware of a real depthmap. I just altered the word as instead of the height of cubes you have to output the 'depth' of cubes. I admit it was perhaps not the best choice.

Comment: Don't worry. It's a fine task as it is now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Golfscript, 42 chars

```
n%{n*~]}%zip:|[]*$),{:);n|{{)>},,}%}%-1%\;
```

results

```
$ golfscript 2657.gs < 2657-1.txt 
0001
1012
1112
1212
2222
3323

$ golfscript 2657.gs < 2657-2.txt 
01
12
22

$ golfscript 2657.gs < 2657-3.txt 
010
211
322
```

Comment: Congratulations.

Comment: @pimvdb, thanks, but I think you should open it without accepting any answer for some time (may be one week).

Comment: Since the accepted answer can be changed any time again, where is the harm?

Comment: +100: 42 chars :-)

Comment: I refrained from looking at your solution until I'd written my own. Comparing them now, they're rather similar except that you save a ton of characters with the `[]*`. Nice trick.

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby 1.9, 102 characters

```
f=$<.map{|g|[*g.chop.bytes]}
f.flatten.max.downto(49){|j|puts f.transpose.map{|n|n.count{|r|r>=j}}*""}
```

Passes all testcases.

Answer (score 7):

### Windows PowerShell, 108 <s>111</s> <s>114</s>

```
(($i=@($input))-split''|sort)[-1]..1|%{$h=$_
-join(1..$i[0].Length|%{$x=$_-1
@($i|?{"$h"-le$_[$x]}).count})}
```

Passes all test cases.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 118 characters

```
import List
p h=map(\c->transpose(lines h)>>=show.length.filter(>=c))['1'..maximum h]
main=interact$unlines.reverse.p
```

---

- Edit (122 → 118): avoid filtering by only iterating to maximal height

Answer (score 4):

### Scala 236 characters

```
object D extends App{var(l,m,z)=(io.Source.stdin.getLines.toList,0,0);val a=Array.ofDim[Int](l.head.size,10);for(i<-l;(j,q)<-i.zipWithIndex;x<-1 to j-48){a(q)(x-1)+=1;m=List(m,j-48).max};for(i<-1 to m){for(j<-a){print(j(m-i))};println}}
```

With some formatting:

```
object Depthmap extends App
{
    var(l,m,z)=(io.Source.stdin.getLines.toList,0,0)
    val a=Array.ofDim[Int](l.head.size,10)
    for(i<-l;(j,q)<-i.zipWithIndex;x<-1 to j-48)
    {
        a(q)(x-1)+=1
        m=List(m,j-48).max
    }
    for(i<-1 to m)
    {
        for(j<-a)
        {
            print(j(m-i))
        }
        println
    }
}
```

I'm sure a better facility with for comprehensions would mean I could cut some characters from this.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, <s>235</s> <s>208</s> 195 bytes

```
function _(b){for(e=Math.max.apply(0,b.join().split(",")),f=[],c=i=0;i<e;i++){for(
c=[],a=0;a<b[0].length;a++)for(d=c[a]=0;d<b.length;d++)b[d][a]>i&&c[a]++;f[e-i-1]
=c.join("")}return f.join("\n")}
```

Just for the record, this is the code I made up before posting the question. (Smallened now)

Answer (score 3):

Haskell Version (Now optimized)

```
import Data.List
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

main= readFile"in.txt">>=(\t->either print(putStrLn.intercalate"\n".map(concatMap show).(\j->map (\n->(map(length.(filter(>=n)))(transpose$reverse j))) (reverse [1..(maximum$map maximum j)])))(parse(many1$many1 digit>>=(\x->newline>>(return$map(read.return)x)))""t))
```

Ungolfed version

```
import Data.List (foldl', transpose, intercalate)
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

-- Source:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/swapping-heightmaps-to-depthmaps

digitArray :: Parser [[Int]]
digitArray = many1 $ do xs <- many1 digit
                        optional newline
                        return $ map (read . return) xs

maxHeight :: Ord c => [[c]] -> c
maxHeight = maximum . (map maximum)

heightToDepth :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
heightToDepth ins = level (maxHeight ins)
        where level 0 = []
              level n = (map (length . (filter (>=n))) xs) : level (n-1)
              xs      = transpose $ reverse ins

lookNice xs = intercalate ['\n'] $ map (concatMap show) xs

main = do inText <- readFile "in.txt"
          case parse digitArray "" inText of
              Left err -> print err
              Right xs -> putStrLn $ lookNice $ heightToDepth xs
```

Comment: Long answers to [code-golf] questions are acceptable when the length arises from using unsuitable languages (say fortran 77), but you are still expected to make an attempt to *golf* them. Not even bothering to reduce your identifiers to single letter is failing to get into the spirit of the game, which I suspect is the cause of the downvotes.

Comment: Welcome to code golf!  Can you separate your golfed code from your ungolfed code, and put a character count in your post for your golfed code please?  Thanks!  It will make your post a little easier to read and is the general pattern we use.

Comment: The goal of code golf is to create the shortest code possible. Yours is rather verbose, so try harder!

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 117 chars

```
import sys
a=zip(*sys.stdin)[:-1]
n=int(max(map(max,a)))
while n:print''.join(`sum(e>=`n`for e in r)`for r in a);n-=1
```

Similar to Ventero's Ruby solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 10 bytes

```
⇌⍉/+⬚0∵↯∶1
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oeM4o2JLyvirJow4oi14oav4oi2MQoKZiBbWzEgNF1bMiAyXVswIDBdXQpmIFtbNSAzIDIgMV1bMSA0IDUgNl1bMiAxIDAgNV1d)

```
⇌⍉/+⬚0∵↯∶1    input: a matrix of numbers
        ∵↯∶1    replace each number with that many 1s repeated...
     ⬚0         ...filling the remaining space in the 3D array with zeros
   /+            sum layers element-wise
⇌⍉              transpose and reverse to put the result in correct orientation
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 14 bytes

```apl
{⊖⍉+⌿⍵≥⍀⍳⌈/,⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR17RHvZ3aj3r2P@rd@qhz6aPehke9mx/1dOjrAAVq/6c9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/P4P@VQCXGCiaPereYKhgrGCkYAqGJgqmCGZhtoGDKxVXJ9ah3DVeaQiUA)

```apl
{⊖⍉+⌿⍵≥⍀⍳⌈/,⍵}    Monadic function:
             ⍵     Start with a 2D array ⍵.
          ⌈/,      Find the overall maximum value h.
         ⍳         Make the list 1...h
       ≥⍀          Make a ≥ table between that list and ⍵.
                   Now we have a 3D matrix where position [a,b,c]
                   represents whether ⍵[a,b] is at least c.
    +⌿             We sum along the outermost (first) dimension, 
                   since that corresponds to a column of ⍵.
                   Now we have a 2D matrix where position [b,c]
                   represents how many values in column b of ⍵ are at least c.
  ⍉                Transpose so the heights are rows.
 ⊖                 Flip vertically.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 102 bytes

```
#(for[h(range(apply max(flatten %))0 -1)](map(fn[w _](count(for[r % :when(>=(r w)h)]_)))(range)(% 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
c rÔÆÕËè>X
w
```

[Try all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YyBy1MbVy+g+WAp3&input=W1tbNSAzIDIgMV0KWzEgNCA1IDZdClsyIDEgMCA1XV0sCgpbWzIgMl0KWzEgM10KWzAgMF1dLAoKW1syIDMgMl0KWzIgMSAwXQpbMSAwIDFdXV0KLVFt)

Outputting the rows in reversed order would save [2 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YyBy1MbVy+g+WA==&input=W1s1IDMgMiAxXQpbMSA0IDUgNl0KWzIgMSAwIDVdXQotUQ==), taking input in column-major order would save [1 byte](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YyBy1MbL6D5YCnc=&input=W1s1IDEgMl0KWzMgNCAxXQpbMiA1IDBdClsxIDYgNV1dCi1R), doing both would (naturally) save [3 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YyBy1MbL6D5Y&input=W1s1IDEgMl0KWzMgNCAxXQpbMiA1IDBdClsxIDYgNV1dCi1R)

Explanation:

```
c rÔ          #Find the maximum height
    Æ         #For each number X in the range [0...max_height]:
     Õ        # Get the columns of the input
      Ë       # For each column:
       è>X    #  Count how many items are greater than X

w             #Reverse the output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 55 bytes

```
!a=[sum(a[:,j].>m-i) for i=1:(m=max(a...)),j=axes(a,2)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVG7boMwFFVXvuKSyZYIwqa0FZGztAxd2g6JVMliMApIRkBRAImO_Y4uWfJR7dfUNg6htmzfxznn-trf53KopDidzkNfrB9-7l3BeDfUSPDYK1N_W68lhuLjCJKRGNWsFiMSvu9j7JVMjHmHhEdxOtF_b776vOs7YMAdHkEIFAhs1LqFCO6Upf0AohTYFngAek4AfVJjkdmi1qJ2bpSglgxTh1OLCdWuVC6CxBINycBC6-kSttAVHNgUMdqGkjq6W9UV5GOLQTZgWnJAjfYomx6tnl9iWGETOciurcQnEngJeN3vZkSmHsMV_8DZlJGFLgEug8z4C4Hk_S153CVPs8qSru9lgnlzuFatGoQdFZl-4vKhfw)